# What is the third-party software on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

And how does it improve my experience or make it easier on me as a user if I choose to use the third-party software

Comment: What third-party software are you talking about?

Comment: @muru It's an option one can select while installing Ubuntu.

Comment: It means you can play dvds and stuff

Answer (score 3):

This includes many common packaages such as Adobe Flash Player, LAME for mp3 encoding, and Microsoft fonts. Installing these packages will allow many everyday applications to work.

These are not installed by default due to being either closed source or open source with licensing restrictions.

For the general user, you should definitely install them. You can do so after installation from the Software Center [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/) [image: Install restricted extras]. Or from a terminal using the following:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`